# getters and setters for custom classes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, class, setter, getter

If you synthesize a custom class, do getters and setters get created for it?

This is the custom class I created.

```
//  MyClass.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSString *string1;
    NSString *string2;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string2;

@end
```

Here I declare an object of that class as a property

```
//  DetailViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyClass.h"


@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {

    MyClass *myObject;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) MyClass *myObject;

@end
```

Here I synthesize the object.

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "MyClass.h"


@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize myObject;
```

So does it have getters and setters?

When I try to run this code inside RootViewController.m

```
DetailViewController.myObject = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I get an error saying "Accessing unkown 'setMyObject:' class method. Object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if you declare the desired instance variables as properties, then `synthesize propname;`, will getters and setters be created. Now, what kind of code goes into the getters and setters depends on what property attributes you define (`nonatomic`/`atomic`, `assign`, `retain`, `copy`)

EDIT to OP's revised question: Yes a getter/setter **will be created for the `myObject` instance variable of the `DetailViewController` class**

`DetailViewController.myObject = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

You are attempting to set a **class variable** that isn't defined. `DetailViewController` is of type `Class`, not `DetailViewController`. Perform the same operation on an **instance** of `DetailViewController` and you should be all set.